# freewall not working when page is refreshed without clearing cache

Tags: javascript, freewalljs

I have a problem using the freewall.js library in my ASP.net website. When i refresh(<kbd>F5</kbd>) the page the freewall is not working and my images are just aligned in a list under each other, but when i refresh with clearing cache(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) or navigate to the page for the first time the freewall works.

my freewall code is in a seperate js file:

```
    $(function () {
    var wall = new Freewall("#freewall");
    wall.reset({
        selector: '.brick',
        animate: true,
        cellW: 400,
        cellH: 'auto',
        onResize: function () {
            wall.fitWidth();
        }
    });

    var images = wall.container.find('.brick');
    images.find('img').on('load',
        function () {
            console.log("hello");
            wall.fitWidth();
            $(window).resize();
        });
});
```

Does anybody have an idea why it only works when accessing the page without cache?